# Are questions about social choice and voting on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, acceptable-questions

In my university, these topics are studied in the economics department. But, since I haven't found any "voting" or "social choice" tags, I would like to know if they are considered on topic.

Comment: I think if they're taught in a university economics department, then definitely!

Answer (score 9):

I think they belong, it is useful to create a tag for that and go on, post your question.