# How can we broaden the site's coverage of the various subfields of economics?

Tags: discussion, site-scope, advertising, site-promotion

Prompted by this recent question, ["Are questions about social choice and voting on-topic here?"](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187/are-questions-about-social-choice-and-voting-on-topic-here), I am starting to worry that we might be losing potential newcomers because the site does not currently seem to cover/welcome questions from their particular subfield of economics? My questions are these:

1. how can we broaden the site's coverage of the various subfields of economics?
2. what subfields are up until now still missing from economics.stackexchange.com?
3. how can we "prime the pump" (so to speak) to help make these subfields seem more welcome?

For example, I haven't seen any questions that cover *economic field experimentation*, questions from *law and economics*, *marketing* (yes, I'm pretty sure that this belongs), *environmental economics* (maybe they're have been questions from this field), *health economics*, *management science*.

In general, there seems to be very little applied economics and little econometrics in general. How can we help improve this?

Comment: I have created another question that I think will help measure the site's coverage: http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/questions/192/creating-a-list-to-measure-the-sites-coverage-of-subfields

Comment: Why the [advertising] tag?

Comment: Maybe it doesn't belong, but I put it there because I figured that an important part of both advertising and promoting the site in its early stage depends on making sure that the site's content appeals to and is relevant to a broad range of economists.

Comment: Cool. I assumed as much but wanted to ensure it wasn't in error or something like that. :-) No worries!

Comment: Oh, OK. Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 3):

I'd say let it come naturally. For whatever there is demand, people will ask questions - don't regulate this market.

The one thing to speed up the process is to invite colleagues from all areas, but I see no reason why we should restrict this to topics with low participation rates.