# Creating a list to measure the site's coverage of subfields

Tags: discussion, site-scope, site-promotion

I'd like to start a list that could serve to measure the site's coverage of subfields of economics. This question is a partial response to the concerns expressed in the question, ["How can we broaden the site's coverage of the various subfields of economics?"](https://economics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191/how-can-we-broaden-the-sites-coverage-of-the-various-subfields-of-economics). As a goal, it would be nice if we could find a question (or ask a new one if one doesn't already exist) from each of the 20 JEL classification categories. I've reproduces the list from the [Wikpedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JEL_classification_codes) here.

There are 20 primary JEL categories:

- JEL: A – General Economics, Handbooks and Teaching
- JEL: B – History of Economic Thought, Methodology, and Heterodox Approaches
- JEL: C – Mathematical and Quantitative Methods
- JEL: D – Microeconomics
- JEL: E – Macroeconomics and Monetary Economics
- JEL: F – International Economics
- JEL: G – Financial Economics
- JEL: H – Public Economics
- JEL: I – Health, Education, and Welfare
- JEL: J – Labor and Demographic Economics
- JEL: K – Law and Economics
- JEL: L – Industrial Organization
- JEL: M – Business Administration and Business Economics; Marketing; Accounting
- JEL: N – Economic History
- JEL: O – Economic Development, Technological Change, and Growth
- JEL: P – Economic Systems
- JEL: Q – Agricultural and Natural Resource Economics; Environmental and Ecological Economics
- JEL: R – Urban, Rural, and Regional Economics
- JEL: Y – Miscellaneous Categories
- JEL: Z – Other Special Topics.

**Could we start by making each answer contain one or more example question from a single JEL category---one answer per JEL category?**

Notes:

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JEL_classification_codes),
Articles in economics journals are usually classified according to the **JEL classification codes**, a system originated by the Journal of Economic Literature.

Comment: In my opinion, we should create the primary JEL categories as _tags_ here (using the letter also), i.e. the name of the tag should be "N-Economic History" etc.

Comment: This might be one of those exceptional cases where [it's worth making this a community wiki.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/)

Comment: Related: [JEL vs tags](http://meta.economics.stackexchange.com/q/198/44)

Comment: Descriptions of the tags: https://www.aeaweb.org/students/Fields.php

Answer (score 2):

#### JEL: B – History of Economic Thought, Methodology, and Heterodox Approaches

**Tags:** [history](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history)

[What was economics like as a field before Adam Smith, the father of *modern* economics?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/140/what-was-economics-like-as-a-field-before-adam-smith-the-father-of-modern-eco)

Answer (score 1):

#### JEL: Q – Agricultural and Natural Resource Economics; Environmental and Ecological Economics

**Tags:** [environmental-economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/environmental-economics)

**Examples:** <sub><sup>(click on one of the tags above for more)</sup></sub>

[Pricing a negative externality under high uncertainty and severe non-linearity](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/128/44)

[A market correction for an industry which has had long-run negative externalities](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/126/44)

Answer (score 1):

#### JEL: C – Mathematical and Quantitative Methods

**Tags:** [mathematical-economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-economics) [econometrics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/econometrics)

**Examples:**  <sub><sup>(click on one of the tags above for more)</sup></sub>

[Topological concepts in economic theory](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/258/topological-concepts-in-economic-theory)

[Dealing with Missing Data when Testing the CAPM](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/485/44)

[Is there always at most one full-support extreme symmetric equilibrium?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/523/44)

Answer (score 1):

#### JEL: J – Labor and Demographic Economics

**Tags:** [labor-economics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/labor-economics)

**Examples:**  <sub><sup>(click on one of the tags above for more)</sup></sub>

[Unemployment and the Minimum Wage---what are the main counter-arguments to Card and Krueger?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/47/44)

[Employment Volatility and the Relevance of Aggregate Wage Rigidity](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/321/44)

Answer (score 1):

#### JEL: E – Macroeconomics and Monetary Economics

**Tags:** [macroeconomics](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macroeconomics)

**Examples:**  <sub><sup>(click on one of the tags above for more)</sup></sub>

[What are main methods for econometrics of Macroeconomics?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/10358/what-are-main-methods-for-econometrics-of-macroeconomics)

[Unemployment and the Minimum Wage---what are the main counter-arguments to Card and Krueger?](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/47/unemployment-and-the-minimum-wage-what-are-the-main-counter-arguments-to-card)

Answer (score 0):

#### JEL: L – Industrial Organization

**Tags:** [industrial-organisation](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/industrial-organisation)

**Examples:**  <sub><sup>(click on one of the tags above for more)</sup></sub>

[Price dispersion in online retail](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/251/price-dispersion-in-online-retail)

[Collusion and number of firms](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/18/collusion-and-number-of-firms)

Comment: The current IO tag has the British English spelling, but it might make sense to standardize on the American English.